# Lower case for a (factor) data frame column

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` in this format:

```
'data.frame':   244 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ names: Factor w/ 244 levels "ERA","BAKE",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

I used this to convert it to lower case:

```
df$names <- tolower(df$names)
```

and as result I get this:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   244 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ names: chr  "era" "bake" "and" "stock price" ...
```

How can I keep the structure of the initial `data.frame` while also converting to lower case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look at the source of `tolower` (you can do this by just entering the variable name `tolower` in the console, or by entering `print(tolower)`):

```
if (!is.character(x)) 
    x <- as.character(x)
```

Your `factor` column is being forced to a `character` vector.

Instead, I believe you want:

```
levels(df$names) <- tolower(levels(df$names))
```

This is also more efficient, since we only have to replace the values of `length(levels(df$names))` in memory, typically much smaller than replacing the full vector of `nrow(df)` values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change column names only, you can try below syntax.

```
colnames(df) <- tolower(colnames(df))
```