# Change case of multiple factor variable values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with both integer and factor variables. Let's call it `df`. It has variables `"a", "b", "c", "d"`. `"a" "c"` are factors.

Several of the factor variables have values that are being treated as unique from one another because of case (e.g., alameda and "ALAMEDA"). My goal is to change all values of all the factor variables to lower case. I saw the following answer that provides a solution for changing one column:
[Lower case for a data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974571/lower-case-for-a-data-frame-column/35974591#35974591).
I've tried modifying that answer to work with all factor variables in a data frame, but to no avail. It seems like my goal could be accomplished with `dplyr::mutate_if()` and using `is.factor` and `tolower(levels())`, but I'm not sure how it all comes together. I think my closest attempt has been `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, tolower(levels()))` but obviously that doesn't work. If there is a way to do this modifying the answer linked to above that would be fine too!

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far! I kept trying and simpliefied to `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, tolower)`. This returned all factor variable values in lowercase in the console, but doesn't seem to actually change `df`.

Comment: Well, `df` will never change unless you reasign the changes to it. You would need to write `df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, tolower)`

Comment: Ah I see now. In hindsight I see I didn't understand the pipe operator, but I've looked it up, and it makes much more sense. One issue I was still having was `tolower()` converting the factor variables to character variables. Nesting `levels()` in `tolower()` took care of that. My final code is `df <- df %>% mutateif(is.factor, tolower(levels(df[])))`. For whatever reason one of the factor variables doesn't change to lowercase, but the capitalization in that variable's values doesn't introduce any unwarranted unique values. Thanks Sraffa!

Answer (score 0):

Single-line solutions can be overrated.  Why not just make your own helper function, then you can customize it further if you find you need it to do more.

```
dftolower <- function(df){
  for(nm in names(df)){
    if(is.factor(df[,nm])){
      levels(df[,nm]) <- tolower(levels(df[,nm]))
    }else if(is.character(df[,nm])){
      df[,nm] <- tolower(df[,nm])
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the levels to lowercase, you could just use a lambda function in the vein of `as.factor(tolower(as.character(x))`:

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% mutate_if(
    .predicate = is.factor,
    .funs = function(x) as.factor(tolower(as.character(x)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't explicit in my question that I wanted to maintain variables as factors. The answer I came up with based on the other answers provided was:

`df <- df %>% mutateif(is.factor, tolower(levels(df[])))`

Comment: mutateif should be mutate_if()  don't know if that is a change.  But even with that change this didn't work form.  I suspect there is some TIdyverse change.